# Deserialize JSON in Webmethod from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, vb.net, json.net

I have a JSON object built in javascript that I would like to pass to an ajax request into a VB.Net WebMethod and deserialize it. I am using Newtonsoft JSON to deserialize the object. It seems like the object is passed over but when I try to deserialize it into an object I get this error : `Error converting value "myid" to type 'AnID.RF.MyIDProfile'.`

Here is the javascript code I am using:

```
function test() {
    var testdata;

    testdata = "{'data':{'ses':'','profile':{'myid':'myid','username':'User','firstName':'adf','lastName':'lastname','languagePreference':'en'}}}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "default.aspx/Foo",
        data: testdata,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != "") {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }

    })
}
```

Here is the server side code:

```
           <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
        Public Shared Function Foo(ByVal data As Object) As String
            Dim jO As JObject = JObject.FromObject(data)
            Dim sMessage As String = "y"
            Try

                Dim results As IList(Of JToken) = jO("profile").Children().ToList()
                Dim searchResults As IList(Of RF.MyIDProfile) = New List(Of RF.MyIDProfile)()

                For Each result As JToken In results
                    Dim searchResult As RF.MyIDProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RF.MyIDProfile)(result.ToString())
                    searchResults.Add(searchResult)
                Next
                Dim stest As String = jO.SelectToken("profile.myid").ToString
            Catch ex As Exception
                sMessage = "e"
            End Try


            Return sMessage
        End Function

        Namespace RF
            Public Class MyIDProfile
                Private sMYID As String
                Private sUSERName As String
                Private sPrefix As String
                Private sFirstName As String
                Private sLastName As String
                Private slanguagePreference As String

                Public Property myid() As String
                    Get
                        Return sMYID
                    End Get
                    Set(ByVal value As String)
                        sMYID = value
                    End Set
                End Property


                Public Property username() As String
                    Get
                        Return sUSERName
                    End Get
                    Set(ByVal value As String)
                        sUSERName = value
                    End Set
                End Property

                Public Property firstName() As String
                    Get
                        Return sFirstName
                    End Get
                    Set(ByVal value As String)
                        sFirstName = value
                    End Set
                End Property

                Public Property lastName() As String
                    Get
                        Return sLastName
                    End Get
                    Set(ByVal value As String)
                        sLastName = value
                    End Set
                End Property

                Public Property languagePreference() As String
                    Get
                        Return slanguagePreference
                    End Get
                    Set(ByVal value As String)
                        slanguagePreference = value
                    End Set
                End Property

            End Class
        End Namespace
```

If I use SelectToken("profile.myid") I am able to get the value with no issues. I am not sure what I could be doing incorrectly that is causing this error. Can anyone take a look and see?

Comment: If you solved your own question, you can (and should) [answer it yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) rather than editing the question to include the answer.  That way others will know the question is answered.  Thanks!

Comment: @dbc I apologize. I thought at the time that it would've been better to just edit the question rather to add it as an answer. Anyways, the solution has been moved to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. The code I had was for deserializing an array of objects and the json object passed through was not an array of objects of which caused the error. I removed the loop and replaced it like so:

```
          <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
         Public Shared Function Foo(ByVal data As Object) As String
                Dim jO As JObject = JObject.FromObject(data)
                Dim sMessage As String = "y"
                Try

                    Dim oDetail As RF.MyIDProfile = jO("profile").ToObject(Of RF.MyIDProfile)()

                    Dim sTest2 As String = oDetail.myid
                Catch ex As Exception
                    sMessage = "e"
                End Try


                Return sMessage
            End Function
```